# como deixa o fundo branco do dropdown

Tags: css, menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Estou com dificuldade de deixar o fundo do dropdown branco (queria poder retirar esse transparente dele)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <!----fonts google------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="js/alerta.js">


  <style>
    .bs-example {
      margin: 50px;
    }

    header {
      z-index: 10;
    }
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates');

h2{
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic');
.numero{font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
opacity: 0.6;
font-size:medium;

}
.iframe-container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 59.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
body{

}
  </style>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <!--------------------------------------------------------- Menu ------------------------------------------------------------>

  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

    <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:1px 5px">
      <h1 class="w3-xlarge">BROWN ODONTOLOGIA</h1>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <h6>SEU SORRISO É NOSSA MISSÃO</h6>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <a href="#menu" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Quem Somos ?</a>
      <a href="#escolher" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Por que nos escolher ?</a>
      <a href="#especia" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Especialidades</a>
      <a href="#chegar" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Como chegar ?</a>

      <div class="w3-button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-center dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contatos</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: white"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"
                style="font-size:19px;color:#1BD741"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="position:">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-phone"
                style="font-size:19px;color:black"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

    <!----------------------------------------------------------Tabela de contatos-------------------------------------------------->


    <!---------------------------------------------------------------Slide--------------------------------------------------------->

    <br />
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Fácil Acesso</h5>
              <p>Como chegar ? </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>O que vale é a qualidade</h5>
              <p>Venha Conhecer Nossos Planos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Próximo </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
      });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que a tag header está com opacidade definida para "0.6". Como você está mexendo na opacidade do elemento "pai" (header), a propriedade "opacity" afeta todos os elementos que estiverem dentro do "header".

Ao invés de declarar a opacidade, você pode declarar uma cor para todos os links e formatar depois apenas os itens do menu.

Adicione nos estilos a seguinte notação para ver como funciona:

```
.w3-opacity, .w3-hover-opacity:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    color: rgba(33,37,41,0.6);
}

.w3-button * {
    color: rgba(33,37,41, 0.6) !important;
}

.w3-button *:hover {
    color: rgba(33,37,41, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <!----fonts google------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="js/alerta.js">


  <style>
    .bs-example {
      margin: 50px;
    }

    header {
      z-index: 10;
    }
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates');

h2{
font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic');
.numero{font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
font-size:medium;

}
.iframe-container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 59.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
body{

}

.w3-opacity, .w3-hover-opacity:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    color: rgba(33,37,41, 0.6);
}

.w3-button * {
    color: rgba(33,37,41, 0.6) !important;
}

.w3-button *:hover {
    color: rgba(33,37,41, 1) !important;
}

  </style>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <!--------------------------------------------------------- Menu ------------------------------------------------------------>

  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

    <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:1px 5px">
      <h1 class="w3-xlarge">BROWN ODONTOLOGIA</h1>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <h6>SEU SORRISO É NOSSA MISSÃO</h6>
      <hr style="line-height:2px; boder:none; color:aquamarine; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;" />
      <a href="#menu" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Quem Somos ?</a>
      <a href="#escolher" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Por que nos escolher ?</a>
      <a href="#especia" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Especialidades</a>
      <a href="#chegar" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Como chegar ?</a>

      <div class="w3-button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-center dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contatos</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: white"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"
                style="font-size:19px;color:#1BD741"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="position:">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right"> <i class="fa fa-phone"
                style="font-size:19px;color:black"></i> WhatsApp</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

    <!----------------------------------------------------------Tabela de contatos-------------------------------------------------->


    <!---------------------------------------------------------------Slide--------------------------------------------------------->

    <br />
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Fácil Acesso</h5>
              <p>Como chegar ? </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://img.ibxk.com.br///2019/04/10/10104113623503-t1200x480.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="#">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>O que vale é a qualidade</h5>
              <p>Venha Conhecer Nossos Planos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Próximo </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
      });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Entendi mais acaba que afetando o titulo , queria fazer uma gambiarra so para afetar as opções do contatos.....

Comment: Isso não é possível, pois você está mexendo na opacidade do elemento "pai". A propriedade "opacity" afeta todos os elementos que estiverem dentro do "header". Você pode, ao invés de declarar opacidade, tentar declarar uma cor para todos os links... é uma opção.

Comment: Reformulei a resposta... espero que te ajude!

Comment: Isso mesmo, @RicardoPareiraDias, reformulou a resposta e ficou bem explicado sobre as hierarquias.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, só vai funcionar se antes você tirar o `opacity` do `<header>` que é o principal, que controla ele.

Definindo o `<header>` como `opacity:1;` aí você consegue controlar o `menu` deixando ele mais transparente ou menos.

Daí, o efeito que você quer  no `header` pode controlar através de cores, deixando a tonalidade mais leve.